# C# Being Able to Search/Manipluate Existing RichTextBoxes That are Differently Named

Tags: c#

With some of the knowledge I gained from yesterday and the day before, I have a general idea of what I want to do. I do have a general question about RichTextBoxes. I have a GUI already made of multiple RichTextBoxes aligned in different rows of one another. One row of boxes monitors the load of a product, the other monitors if one of the channels have been tripped and the other two rows displays the current and voltage of the product. The GUI has been premade and each row of product has been named `StatusOutxxx, TripStatOutxxx, VoltageOutxxx and CurrentOutxxx` (the `xxx` indicates a number of each RichTextBox, like `CurrentOut001`, for example).

The example gui is listed below:

[image]

From the image, you can see that I have 4 rows of RichTextBoxes. The monitoring backend of the product has already been established and I am trying to take the data and turn the product into a user friendly display to let the person now, if the load on a certain channel is okay or if the voltage of a product is too high/low or if a certain channel has been tripped.

Now, I know how to turn them all on at once via:

```
foreach(var rtb in this.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>())
    rtb.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
```

and I know how to control which ones to turn on via `if(rtb.Name.StartsWith("Insert Prefix Here"))`. But I am asking a bit of a harder question in terms of searching and manipulating an individual RichTextBox.

For example, if there is a load issue on Channel 17 of my product that drops my voltage, I want to be able to search for the `StatusOut017`, change the backcolor of that to Red and change the value of `VoltageOut017` to the voltage display.

I know that the long way of doing it is doing a giant if statement for each load, trip and voltage channel to change it, but I am aiming for reducing the amount of lines of code and attempting to doing a for loop so my code will look something like this (in psuedocode):

```
for (i = 1; i < 25; i++)
{
    if (StatusOut[i] == true)
    {
        StatusOut[i].BackColor == Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        StatusOut[i].BackColor == Color.Red;
    }

    if (TripStatOut[i] == true)
    {
        TripStatOut[i].BackColor == Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        TripStatOut[i].BackColor == Color.Red;
    }

    VoltageOut[i].Text = VoltageReading;
    CurrentOut[i].Text = CurrentReading;
}
```

I am hoping for some help on this one.

Comment: Any reason for having multiple rich text boxes instead of the usual data grid?

Comment: Pretty much _user friendly_. Essentially, the person that will be using it will just see if the Load failed or the Trip Status has failed, they do not need to see the official calls made to the product.

Plus the product is being monitored over time so those 24 channels will be observed and data taken every minute. But all that backend is done, the issue is dealing with GUI (which has been a struggle coming from working on an older version visual basic).

Comment: Well this is definitely a UI from the past century. Not only it complicates usability, it also makes your like as a programmer into a nightmare. Regarding solution to your problem, please reduce number of rows to 3 and repeat/rephrase your question.

Comment: The thing is, I know the _easy_ solution is to just make a giant if/else statement for each Trip/Load/Voltage/Current, but it feels really inefficient to do that, I was trying to aim for something more compact so I don't have an extra 200 lines of code.

Comment: if these are rich textboxes why the sample: StatusOut[i] == true  ??  What value ends up in this control.  I have a solution but need to understand a bit more

Comment: The right approach is to have a data grid and manipulate at business logic level, which for most simple implementation would be data rows. Data grid control will handle the tedious work for you. Consider the situation if your app is going to change (99.9% of the time), like adding a column - what would the effort be in your current approach? What would it be with data grids ? (hint: almost no effort) What about adding or reducing rows? Grouping functionality etc. This can easily add up 2 years of dev time, or be done in a snap using a good data grid.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your naming convention is Name then 3 digits for the RichTextBox controls.  You can use the controls collection to match the corresponding controls for that row.   As noted a DataGrid would be better.

```
    private void ChangeStatus()
    {
        //loop through the RichtextBoxes
        foreach (RichTextBox rtb in this.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>())
        {
            Color c = Color.Green; //default to good value
            //only handle the status Out Control
            if (rtb.Name.StartsWith("StatusOut"))
            {   ///check the value and set the color if false
                if (rtb.Text == "false")
                    c = Color.Red;
                //update the controls
                rtb.BackColor = c;
                //string controlNum = rtb.Name.Replace("StatusOut", ""); //If it is not 3 just use replace since we know we are on the StatusOut control
                string controlNum = rtb.Name.Substring(rtb.Name.Length - 3);
                ((RichTextBox)Controls["TripStateOut" + controlNum]).BackColor = c;
                ((RichTextBox)Controls["VoltageOut" + controlNum]).Text = VoltageReading;
                ((RichTextBox)Controls["CurrentOut" + controlNum]).Text = CurrentReading;
            }
        }            
    }
```